# How do you retrieve transitive groups of user with Java Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to retrieve all the groups (including transitive) that a user is a member of

Using this API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/780b6216-3ae0-4396-975d-3739d5cbb063/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group

I'm using:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
      <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code looks like:

```java
    GroupCollectionPage collection = azure
            .users(oid)
            .transitiveMemberOfAsGroup()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
    
    
    List<AzureAdGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while (collection != null) {
        final List<Group> directoryObjects = collection.getCurrentPage();
    
        List<AzureAdGroup> groupsFromPage = directoryObjects.stream()
                .filter(group -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(group.securityEnabled))
                .map(group -> new AzureAdGroup(group.id, group.displayName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        groups.addAll(groupsFromPage);
    
        GroupCollectionRequestBuilder nextPage = collection
                .getNextPage();
        if (nextPage == null) {
            break;
        } else {
            collection = nextPage.buildRequest().get();
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
2021-06-15 07:26:29.134+0000 [id=91]    INFO    c.a.c.util.logging.ClientLogger#performLogging: Azure Identity => getToken() result for scopes [https://graph.microsoft.com/.default]: SUCCESS
2021-06-15 07:26:29.580+0000 [id=70]    SEVERE  c.m.graph.logger.DefaultLogger#logError: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 396Error during http request
2021-06-15 07:26:29.580+0000 [id=70]    SEVERE  c.m.graph.logger.DefaultLogger#logError: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
2021-06-15 07:26:29.580+0000 [id=70]    WARNING
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 3384 path $.value[3]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1562)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:475)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:413)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:714)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:723)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:698)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$35$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:894)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
Caused: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:947)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:870)
    at com.microsoft.graph.serializer.DefaultSerializer.deserializeObject(DefaultSerializer.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.handleJsonResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:527)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.processResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:455)
Caused: com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.processResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:483)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:396)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:222)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:199)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseCollectionRequest.send(BaseCollectionRequest.java:102)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseEntityCollectionRequest.get(BaseEntityCollectionRequest.java:78)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azuread.AzureCachePool.lambda$getBelongingGroupsByOid$2(AzureCachePool.java:41)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2405)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1908)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2403)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2386)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:62)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azuread.AzureCachePool.getBelongingGroupsByOid(AzureCachePool.java:34)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azuread.AzureSecurityRealm.lambda$doFinishLogin$3(AzureSecurityRealm.java:382)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2405)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1908)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2403)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2386)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:62)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azuread.AzureSecurityRealm.doFinishLogin(AzureSecurityRealm.java:375)
    ...
0)org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

This works but I would like to retrieve only groups (and then filter on securityGroup only as well):

```java
DirectoryObjectCollectionWithReferencesPage collection = azure
        .users(oid)
        // TODO asGroup isn't working json error, and neither is $filter on securityEnabled
        .transitiveMemberOf()
        .buildRequest()
        .get();


List<AzureAdGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();

while (collection != null) {
    final List<DirectoryObject> directoryObjects = collection.getCurrentPage();

    List<AzureAdGroup> groupsFromPage = directoryObjects.stream()
            .filter(group -> group instanceof Group
                    && Boolean.TRUE.equals(((Group) group).securityEnabled))
            .map(group -> new AzureAdGroup(group.id, ((Group) group).displayName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    groups.addAll(groupsFromPage);

    DirectoryObjectCollectionWithReferencesRequestBuilder nextPage = collection
            .getNextPage();
    if (nextPage == null) {
        break;
    } else {
        collection = nextPage.buildRequest().get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

DirectoryObjectCollectionWithReferencesPage transitiveMemberOf = graphClient.groups("{id}").transitiveMemberOf()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();

List<DirectoryObject> page = transitiveMemberOf.getCurrentPage();

for (DirectoryObject directoryObject : page) {
    Check --> directoryObject.oDataType

...
```

Comment: That's getting the group membership of groups isn't it? Not getting the users group memberships?